# Trapping R Errors in rpy2

Tags: r, exception, rpy2

When I use RStudio, I can see any errors or warnings when I run a function.

However when I am using, rpy2, how can I catch warnings (which allow the code to run) and errors (which stall the code) so I can parse the messages programmatically in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until R-3.0 (current unreleased), warnings were printed to the console by default.
From R-3-0, they are no longer printed because the R developers made the C function previously used hidden (and are too busy to document why and tell whether we could get access to that function back or not).

To get the warnings as an rpy2 object, you can do:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
# do things that generate R warnings
base.warnings()
```

Errors occurring while evaluating R code raise an `rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError`. Just catch those.

Comment: @lgautier it seems that not all R runtime errors generate ``rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError``s.  I'm getting the following

    ```>error: inv_sympd(): matrix appears to be singular

>error: chol(): failed to converge terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
>what():  chol(): failed to converge
>Aborted (core dumped)```

and this exits me out of Python completely. Note that the R-code I'm running is within a try/except block.

Comment: @DrMisha it's a old answer but anyways, the error you seem to be having in R is related to C++ (as can be seen from the `std::runtime_error`) and not properly caught by the R library that you are using. When that happens it is virtually impossible for `rpy2` to properly handle the error since the error is causing R to [dump a core ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump). Hope this helps.